# ST_CLIP with one raster and one polygon

Tags: postgis, gdal, sql

I don't understand how I can select a raster and polygon by ID and then clipping them.

Something like:

```
SELECT ST_CLIP(selected_raser.rast, 1, selected_polygon.geometry)
From
     raster WHERE ID = 99 AS selected_raster,
     Polygon WHERE ID = 999 AS selected_polygon;
```

But somehow I can't Do WHERE for multiple tables. Do I have to join or combine them before?

Comment: Your *are* joining them - with an implicit `CROSS JOIN`. You can only have a single `WHERE` block per query, but you can combine its statements *logically* (e.g. `AND`). This is *very fundamental* language syntax - you want to give it a deep dive, if only to save you heaps of pain...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a raster table named **nh**, and a polygon table named **polygon**.

I want to clip raster with rid=1 with polygon with id=1:

```
CREATE TABLE test.clipped_raster AS
SELECT 1 AS id, st_clip(r.rast, p.geom) AS rast
FROM test.nh AS r
JOIN test.polygons AS p
ON st_intersects(r.rast, p.geom)
WHERE r.rid=1 AND p.id=1
```

[image]

Comment: I had to add add the "::geometry" cast method to the inputs of ST_INTERSECTS and to the polygon for ST_CLIP. Then it worked perfectly. Thank you!